# convert flycapture.Image to Mat

Tags: java, opencv, flycapture

I am trying to convert FlyCapture2.Image to Opencv Mat in java and I dont know why its not working.
sorry for my bad eng and noob question :D

```
cam.RetrieveBuffer(rawImage);
org.bytedeco.javacpp.FlyCapture2.Image rgbImage=new org.bytedeco.javacpp.FlyCapture2.Image(); 
rawImage.Convert(PIXEL_FORMAT_BGR, rgbImage);
int rowBytes = rgbImage.GetReceivedDataSize()/rgbImage.GetRows();
Mat frame = new Mat(rgbImage.GetRows(), rgbImage.GetCols(), CvType.CV_8UC3, rgbImage.GetData(), rowBytes);
```

Comment: I can see  there is no that kind of constructor in java but how can I convert it to Mat in Java

Comment: point grey newsletter mentioned opencv support lately, but not sure whether java api was mentioned there...

Comment: looks like it only covered c++ https://www.ptgrey.com/KB/10861